# Implementing a tree view in a Windows 10 app

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

Im creating a Universal windows app that would read 'Favorites' from Chrome and display it as a tree view. The favorites are fetched from the Bookmarks file of Chrome Browser, however implementing a tree view structure for windows 10 is where I'm facing the problem. All the samples I found were usually for Windows 8.1 and no tree view control is present for windows 10 by default. Can someone kindly provide a solution to implement a tree view in a UWP

Comment: There is a TreeView Control in [WinRT XAML Toolkit for Windows 10](https://www.nuget.org/packages/winrtxamltoolkit.uwp), you can refer to its [source code](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit/tree/master/WinRTXamlToolkit.UWP/Controls/TreeView) in GitHub to implement your onw.

Comment: Updated link to [source code](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit/tree/master/WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/TreeView)

Answer (score 0):

As it descriped in [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tree-view)

> A TreeView is a hierarchical list pattern with expanding and collapsing nodes that contain nested items. Nested items can be additional nodes or regular list items. You can use a ListView to build a tree view to illustrate a folder structure or nested relationships in your UI.

So use a `ListView` to implement a tree view. The sample is available here:
[TreeView (XAML) sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlTreeView)

Comment: I have looked at it and see `using TreeViewControl;` in the code behind and cannot seem to find out where **TreeViewControl** is coming from. It's not on the docs page either. Is it from the WinRT toolkit like @Jay Zuo says?

Comment: @JPHellemons No. it is not an independent TreeViewControl. It's a ListView with some implementations that results a TreeView

Comment: I was sleepy, the Treeview XAML control is indeed a ListView control. The complete project is C++ and can be referenced from any other project. https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlTreeView/cpp/Control I did not bother to look in the cpp folder, because I was looking for C#. My bad!